# Magento 2 - Saving custom entity

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2-extensions

I just created a custom entity at mage2gen, links bellow:
https://mage2gen.com/download/195a0734-62bc-4b0d-9fb4-b352878a9c2e.tar
https://mage2gen.com/load/195a0734-62bc-4b0d-9fb4-b352878a9c2e

Although, i'm having problems to save those entities, I don't know how I should to do that, I have tried lots of given solution I found, can anyone help me?

Constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Trezo\Sigep\Helper\Data $helper,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Trezo\Sigep\Model\SigepwebPostcardObjectFactory $factory,
    \Trezo\Sigep\Model\SigepwebPostcardObjectRepository $repository
)
```

I tried that:

```
$object = $this->factory->create();
$object->addData($data);
$object->save();

$object = $this->factory->create();
$object->addData($data);
$this->repository->save($object);

$object =  $this->_objectManager->create('Trezo\Sigep\Model\SigepwebPostcardObject');
$object->addData($data);
$object->save();
```